# Confusion related to derivative of a quadratic equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This might be a simple question  but how come

```
F(x) = x'Ax

F'(x) = (A + A')x
```

I didn't get it

Comment: Does $x'=x^t$ (the transpose?). Also, It'd be better if you show what "you didn't get", that is, give us the extract where it was proven that $F'$ equals that, so we can help you with the part you didn't understand.

Comment: It doesn't look like it.  (x'Ax)' is not equal to (A + A')x.

Comment: @James, I believe OP uses primes in two ways. For x' and A', OP means transpose. But the other prime is $\nabla$, the gradient operator.

Comment: Oh, right on.  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3):

$F$ takes column vectors $\vec{x}$ as input and outputs real numbers. (I am assuming that by x', you mean the transpose of $\vec{x}$ and that $A$ is square.)

I guess by $F'(\vec{x})$, you mean a vector whose $i$th entry is the partial derivative of $F$ with respect to $x_i$, aka $\nabla F(\vec{x})$.

Well, one way is just to write out $F(\vec{x})$ as a quadratic polynomial: $$F(\vec{x})=\sum_{j,k}a_{jk}x_jx_k$$

Now applying $\partial_i$: $$\begin{align}F_i(\vec{x})&=\overbrace{\sum_{k\neq i}a_{ik}x_k}^{\text{from terms of the form } a_{ik}x_ix_k}+\overbrace{\sum_{j\neq i}a_{ji}x_j}^{\text{from terms of the form } a_{ji}x_jx_i}+\overbrace{2a_{ii}x_i}^{\text{from terms of the form } a_{ii}x_ix_i}\\
&=\sum_{k}a_{ik}x_k+\sum_{j}a_{ji}x_j\end{align}$$

And this is exactly the $i$th entry of $(A+A^t)\vec{x}$.